# (Power Query) Sort Surnames with a Prefix

Tags: excel, sorting, powerquery

I have a list of names that I want to sort in Power Query. Let's say it looks like this:

```
Bloggs, Joe  
West, Pete  
de Villers, Jose
```

And after sorting it still looks like that!

It seems that the prefix with "de Villers" is causing an inappropriate sort but despite wasting an hour searching Google I can't find the answer.

I don't really care if "de Villers" is sorted by "d" or "V" but placing it at the bottom of the list isn't working.

Thanks,

Chris

original question was Sort these:

```
Bloggs
Joe West
Pete de Villers
Jose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this which sorts on last item after space and first item before space

```
= List.Sort(Source, (x, y) => Value.Compare(
    List.Last(Text.Split(Text.Upper(x)," "))&List.First(Text.Split(Text.Upper(x)," ")),
    List.Last(Text.Split(Text.Upper(y)," "))&List.First(Text.Split(Text.Upper(y)," "))
))
```

[image]

**Edited Answer for changed requirements**.

Since the new requirement already is last-name first, this will sort the list ignoring case

```
Sorted = List.Sort(Source, (x, y) => Value.Compare(Text.Upper(x), Text.Upper(y)))
```

[image]

Comment: I think this looks like it would work (haven't had tome to try it yet) but I've edited my question so the names to be sorted are more obvious.

Comment: Please dont change the requirements after your question has been asked and answered. That said, I have provided an alternative answer

Comment: Did this work for you and solve the question?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks horseyride